# List Google Hangouts App on Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have developed an app using Google Hangouts API.
Now we want to list it on Google Apps Marketplace.
We have tried to add the Google Apps Marketplace SDK service to the app but it erases the settings of the Hangouts API page. These two services don't seem to work together.

Does anybody know if this can work? How long does Google usually take to reply to the Listing Review Request form?

Answer (score 0):

The Listing Review process is a reactive process after your app is already published in the Google Apps Marketplace (via the Chrome Web Store)

Have you already listed the app on the Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot list Hangout Apps on the Google Apps Marketplace. In order for users to launch your Hangout App, use the the [Hangouts Button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button).